# Partial HTML rendering without auto closing HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have something like

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

and sequentially add new text to it:

```js
content = document.getElementById(`content`);
content.innerHTML += "<p>The paragraph starts"
(later)
content.innerHTML += " and ends.</p>"
```

However, it seems that the browser is automatically adding start and closing tags as needed.

The resulting HTML looks like this:

```html
<p>The paragraph starts</p> and ends.<p></p>
```

The expected result was

```html
<p>The paragraph starts and ends.</p>
```

Since I'm dealing with a **real-time application** where the server sequentially sends parts of the document, I don't have the chance to construct a valid HTML before showing it.

Is there any way I can change/avoid the behaviour or work around it?

**MVE**

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = (event) => {
        content = document.getElementById("content")
        content.innerHTML = "<p>The paragraph starts"
        setTimeout(function(){
            content.innerHTML += " and ends.</p>"
        }, 3000);
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's just not the right way to build elements. They aren't strings of HTML. They're DOM nodes. Think of it like that and refactor to inject text rather than appending it.

Comment: There is no browser API to control the way assignment to `.innerHTML` works.

Comment: @NicoHaase It def. doesn't answer the question because there it justs suggest to add the strings before showing it, while there is no chance for me doing that since the subsequent parts will arrive later. Waiting would obviously introduce much latency.

Comment: You seem to be saying that you can't change the process. What _can_ you change?

Comment: Build the p tag with `document.createElement()`. Build the string that goes in it, then set the p tag's innerHTML.

Comment: Well, if we assume strings arrive like this ("<p>The paragraph starts", " and ends.</p>", ...), it should be considered what I can do in the frontend to properly display it. With the end result being "<p>The paragraph starts and ends.</p>".

Comment: The other answer clearly tells you that you cannot start fiddling around with `innerHTML` when using invalid markup. The obvious way to go is avoid `innerHTML` with invalid markup

Comment: If your API returns invalid markup, you need to fix that first

Comment: The point of this question is not innerHTML, I'm open to alternatives.

Comment: Why not gather the whole API response and exchange the whole `content.innerHTML`  instead of appending?

Comment: @NicoHaase That's mentioned in the question. The end tag can arrive seconds/minutes later, since it's a real-time application and we don't necessarily know at which point the paragraph ends.

Comment: Then put whatever your API sends in a variable, append all new data to that variable, write the full content of that variable to the markup instead of using `innerHTML` to append new content. Also, please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Well the bottom line is that the assumption that the application can dribble out HTML in incomplete pieces is wrong.  You can't do that, clearly. Thus the solution is to re-think how the content from the real-time application is to be delivered.

Comment: @Pointy I have not really assumed that. If that's a limitation, then, as mentioned in the question, I wonder how we might "work around it" to still make it work as expected given the circumstances -- and as the answers show, there indeed might be ways to do that.

Comment: Well you could perhaps accumulate the fragments into a string *outside* of the DOM, and each time a new fragment arrives you would repaint the entire page. Browsers can do that very quickly. The content accumulator can of course be the "core" of the page, so that initially you start with just the `<head>` and an empty `<body>`, and the content updates could replace the `<body>` content with all content so far. The browser will still "correct" the markup, but that would not matter .... oh wait I just noticed that somebody answered with this idea :)

Answer (score 4):

You could remember the text/html in a variable and replace all the content each time you get more text:

```
async function mockTextSender() {
  let sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
  sleep(3000);
  getText('<p>Some text');
  sleep(3000);
  getText('and som more');
  sleep(3000);
  getText(`and that's it</p>`);
}
mockTextSender();

let htmlMemory = '';
function getText(text) {
  htmlMemory += text;
  $('.myDiv').innerHTML = htmlMemory;
}
```

Comment: Yea I think this is the best idea. The browser will still "fix" the markup, but that won't matter because each update will clean the slate.

Comment: And depending on the actualities of the application, the updates might be updating the `<body>` of the document, or (as in this answer) a `<div>` or `<section>` or whatever somewhere inside static content.

Comment: NB, for demo purposes you don't even need any "anynchronous delay". Each innerHTML change is blocking and atomic, so synchronously setting innerHTML twice must also construct full respective DOM fragment twice. Browsers are not allowed to "merge" those assignments to a single batch. (It could be nice performance boost, but they cannot do that.)

Comment: Yes I just wanted to simulate the delay to have time to see how the page changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use createElement and have a variable with the content to create the paragraph. Then in your setTimeout add to your innerHTML then append to the content div.

```js
const content = document.getElementById("content")
let str = "The paragraph starts";
let p = document.createElement("p")

setTimeout(function() {
  str += " and ends."
  p.innerHTML = str;
  content.append(p)
}, 3000);
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```